# Importing performance monitor settings from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, perfmon

On Windows Server 2003, I have some performance counters set up in Performance Monitor (perfmon). I would like to use these same counters on some new Windows Server 2008 servers. How do I import these performance counters to 2008?

In 2003 I can export the counters a .html files. Can I convert them somehow?

I figure this must be a pretty common task, however, I have not been able to find a solution.